# How to print system("date") in printf in C?

Tags: c

Is there a way to do something like this.

```
printf("Display Time is %S\n",system("date"));
```

I know I can use the time structure to printout the date but I would like to know whether I can do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system("date > out.txt");`

after read out.txt

or

popen()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just look at `man strftime`, or look [here](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strftime.3.html#EXAMPLES).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it involves time structure right. How to do it without involving time structure?

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is a year old, but I found a solution that works better for me:

```
printf("Date: %s %s\n",__DATE__,__TIME__);
```

Comment: __ DATE __ actually refers to the time the preprocessor was run/file was compiled. It is not what the OP is asking for.